# Overwriting a few lines in a file only if specific criteria are met

Tags: python, string-formatting, file-handling

I have 2 files named:

#### inp1:

```
recev: Na Sod B 1    
                accept: F Fluorin B 91           R-A = 12.44 
                        I Iodin  C 22            R-A = 22.11 
                        Cl chlorine D 21         R-A = 24.21  

recev: Mg Mag C 3 
                accept: F Fluorin B 82          R-A = 91.00
                        Mn Mangan C 23          R-A = 12.30
...(100+ lines)
```

#### inp2:

```
recev: Na Sod B 1   H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2  
recev: Mg Mag C 3   H-atom: H Hydrogen N 3  
...(100+lines)
```

Now, I was trying to replace `recev` row of `inp1` with the row from `inp2` file putting a search criteria like `if len(lines) == 5 : (then replace)`. But please suggest any ideas on how can I replace efficiently maintaining all formatting in `inp1` file.

Desired Result:

```
recev: Na Sod B 1  H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2  
             accept: F Fluorin B 91           R-A = 12.44 
                     I Iodin  C 22            R-A = 22.11 
                     Cl chlorine D 21         R-A = 24.21  

recev: Mg Mag C 3  H-atom: H Hydrogen N 3
             accept: F Fluorin B 82          R-A = 91.00
                     Mn Mangan C 23          R-A = 12.30
```

Comment: Can you please show the desired result, and also what have you tried?

Comment: Are the entries in `inp2` in the same order as the entries in `inp1`?  Do you have to worry about an entry in `inp2` that has no match in `inp1`?  Is it only `recev:` lines that will be changed?  Presumably, you're seeking the revised data on standard output, and will let other code worry about overwriting the file?  Is it always the first five fields of the entry in `inp2` that must match the entry in `inp1`, or is the match based on fewer than 5 fields? Why is the formatting of the `Cl chlorine` line wonky (lower-case c on Chlorine; odd spacing around `R-A=24.21` compared with other lines)?

Comment: ya! so far i have generated the code that gonna provide all data in 'inp2' with same order as in 'inp1'.
Yes, only 'recev:' line i want to change that's why i'm trying to use the 'if loop'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully optimized but this should work

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import re
 with open('inp1') as f1, open('inp2') as f2:
     inp1 = f1.readlines()
     inp2 = f2.readlines()

 dict1 = {l.split('   ')[0] : l.split('   ')[1] for l in inp2}

 for line in inp1:
     line = line.rstrip()
     if re.match('recev:',line):
          if dict1.has_key(line):
              line = ' '.join([line, dict1[line].rstrip()])
     print line #write this line to file
```

Comment: @abhisek I think possible coz may be file format. My suggestion is please try example with file that you have mentioned in question section (assuming you have tried on actual files) it will be easy to debug, also try printing dict1 object and see its contents, also please verify splitting string (e.g. '   ' three spaces i used, It can be diff. if your file format is diff.)

Comment: Try printing 

for l in inp2:
    print l.spilt('   ') #three spaces 
    
The output should be some what 
>>>{'recev: Na Sod B 1' : 'H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2\n'} so on....

Comment: thank u.. but data is same as in my file though I am getting IndexError while executing.. @nikhil

Comment: the line is "dict1 = ...." showing 'list index out of range'..
i was thinking will "try:... except:" loop gonna help or not.. @nikhil

Comment: Yes try except and traceback will give some clearity but

I think splitting is problem 
`l.spilt('   ')[0] or value = l.spilt ('   ')[1]` is giving error
comment dict comprehension i have used that is dict1=.... line
and use manual update to dict


`dict1 = {}

for l in inp2:
    key = l.spilt('   ')[0]
    value = l.spilt ('   ')[1]
    dict1.update({key:value})`

Comment: I update my above comment (second one) Try printing `for l in inp2: print l.spilt(' ') #three spaces`. The output should be some what `['recev: Na Sod B 1','H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2\n']` so on.. for each line

Comment: yup!! i got it.. there were some spacing prob with 'inp2' file.. that's why it is generating IndexError.. i updated my previous code and it works very fine now... thank you for your kind help..
but being a rookie I still have a question, in the line "dict1 = {l.split('   ')[0]:....." what is the significance of 3 spaces? @nikhil

Comment: Thats great ! the line dict1={l.split(' ')[0]...} is just creating a dict with key and value. the three space is the criteria to split the line so that we could get `recev: Na Sod B 1` as key and `H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2` as value when we are splitting l.split(' ') by three space, if there is space not equal to three it will not split correctly we will not get `['recev: Na Sod B 1','H-atom: H Hydrogen D 2\n']` this list format for line after splitting, so when you try to access l.spilt(' ')[1] it gives index error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correcly, but as I understand you have to do the following:

Keep every line of inp2 file in the list of strings. Search for lines which are starting with "recev:" in inp1 file. Every time if the condition "if len(lines) == 5" is satisfied for line which contains "recev:", replace that line with the first element of the kept list. Remove first element of the list every time when "recev:" containing line is found in inp1 file.